# How to convert this 2 columns data into a Tree in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Say, I got a 2 column table

```
Parent - Child
135 - 140
140 - 141
141 - 142
141 - 145
135 - 149
149 - 150
```

The top father ("135") is the first value in Parent column.

The data can be put into a List.

```
        List<String[]> myList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String[] s1={"135","140"};
        String[] s2={"140","141"};
        String[] s3={"141","142"};
        String[] s4={"141","145"};
        String[] s5={"135","149"};
        String[] s6={"149","150"};
        myList.add(s1);
        myList.add(s2);
        myList.add(s3);
        myList.add(s4);
        myList.add(s5);
        myList.add(s6);
```

What is the minimum Java code (probably use a very elegant algorithm) to convert the above data into a tree like this:

```
+ 135
   + 140
      + 141
         + 142
         + 145
   + 149
      + 150
```

Note: some other solutions i found were to create an extra table in DB, but i don't want that. There only 1 above table in DB. I just want a pure algorithm to convert it to the tree.

Comment: You should declare which node is the root of the tree

Comment: 135 is the top father

Comment: Convert the data to tree is easy, but output the tree in that format is not so easy. So do you really cares about the output format?

Comment: ok, can u just provide your solution?. Actually I need a Tree gui.

Comment: Just convert the datas into a 2D-array(f[i][j]=1 means node i is the father of node j),or some other data structures.

Comment: is there any similar link saying convert 2 column data into an 2D Array?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {int a=scanner.nextInt();int b=scanner.nextInt();f[a][b]=1;} That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a simple tree, best is to use a custom class to represent the concept of a Node, and have either two child nodes, or an array of child nodes, depending on size.

But, if you don't even want to use structure just use a HashMap

```
HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> tree = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();

for (String line: input){
    String ints = line.split(" - ");
    Integer k = Integer.valueOf(ints[0]);
    Integer v = Integer.valueOf(ints[1]);
    List<Integer> children = tree.get(k);
    if (children == null){
        children = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        tree.put(k,children);
    }
    children.add(v);

    printIt(135, 0, tree);
}

 public static void printIt(Integer node, Integer depth, HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> tree){
    System.out.println(getSpaces(depth) +"+ "+node);
    if (tree.containsKey(node)){
        for (Integer n : tree.get(node)){
            printIt(n, depth+1, tree);
        }
    }
}
public static String getSpaces(int depth){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0;i<depth;i++){
        sb.append("  ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but how to loop it so it print out the tree as required?

Comment: Thax u very much for your help. It works very nicely.